# Check if a key exists in a GraphUser object (FB SDK 3.0 Android)

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How can I check if a key exists in a GraphUser object. I am making a request to the Facebook API that will return all my friends. Once the friends are returned I am then able to check if the friend has the app installed. However once the friend doesn't have the app installed then the key/property is not returned at all. I dont know why Facebook did this. They could have just returned "false" or "0". So I am wondering how can I check to see if the key exists or not. The GraphUser object does not have a hasProperty() or hasElement() function so I am not sure how to do it.

```
public  List<GraphUser> installedUsers(List<GraphUser> users)
{

    for(GraphUser user:users)
    {
        if((Boolean)user.getProperty("installed")==true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I simply created a Map object and passed the user to it like so.

```
Map<String,Object> check = user.asMap();
```

Once I did this, I was then able to check if a key exists in the object by calling the *containsKey()* function.

```
if(check.containsKey("installed"))
```